# The Extracted data retrieved from XML in MySQL duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

MySQL version 10.1.13-MariaDB

I need to retrieve the value for m attribute in a particular element iteratively

```
SELECT ExtractValue( 
'<a>
    <b>
        <c m="e1">
            <k>asde1</k>
        </c>
        <c m="e2">
            <k>asdae2</k>
        </c>
        <c m="e3">
            <k>asdae3</k>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c m="l1">
            <k>asdl1</k>
        </c>
        <c m="l2">
            <k>asdal2</k>
        </c>
        <c m="l3">
            <k>asdal3</k>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>',

'//@m[1]' ) AS result;
```

My result is

```
e1 e2 e3 l1 l2 l3
```

What I need is

```
e1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query

```
SELECT ExtractValue( 
'SomeXML',
'//@m[1]' ) AS result;
```

performs a deep search, due to the `//` at the beginning of your `XPath`. This means: *Find **any** attribute with the name "m" and return its value!*

With XML it is always a good idea to be a specific as possible:

```
SELECT ExtractValue( 
'SomeXML',
'/a[1]/b[1]/c[1]/@m' ) AS result;
```

This means: *Start from the root and search for the first "a", there search for the first "b" and there for the first "c". This element has got an attribute "m".*

You might test it here: 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/77760

Comment: @tymspy, Okay, I'm familiar with SQL-Server syntax... Please see my update